# MongoDB Having Multiples Schema Why Is It Choosing Last Schema

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express, mongoose

I made a architectural decision to use multiple schemas since it is allowed rather than use different database and having to deal with clusters. I have noticed that when using the model rather than the collection it use the last schema.  I'm not sure why that is.  Temporarily I moved the schema in question to the end, I need to get to the source of the issue or why this is happening, this is why I proposed the question. I don't want it to cause problems later. For some logic since the code was already developed and working before adding the new schemas. I don't want to have to refactor the code since it is working.  I have include some code and an example below. I would appreciate some direction.

Backend Schema
search.cjs file

```
 const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
   _id:{
    type: String,
    required: true
 }

 });
 const wishitemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
    type:String,
    required:true
    }

 });
 const cartitemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id:{
        type: String
        required: true.

     },
    mame:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    }

  
    }); 

 

module.exports = mongoose.model('Products',  productSchema,  'products');
module.exports = mongoose.model('Wishitems', wishitemSchema, 'wishitems');
module.exports = mongoose.model('Cartitems', cartitemSchema, 'cartitems');

example of query
api
 const Products      = require('../../../Search.cjs');
 const Wishitems     = require('../../../Search.cjs');
 const Cartitems     = require('../../../Search.cjs');

router.post('/getProducts',  async(req, res) =>{
let search = await Products.find({name: {$regex: new RegExp('^'+payload+'.*',
'i')}}).exec();

 .......
 })
 //it will give me data from the last schema.

  // If I try to use this logic above with a collection it won't work use
    .router.get(/getProducts, async(req, res =>{
     db.collection('products').find({})

    ,,,,
   })
 /*This does not work with the logic I'm using above, I have to stick with what works
 so what I did was. Note with the deletes I can use the say for example WishItems vs the 
 collection */

/* When I do this it works as expected*/

 module.exports = mongoose.model('Wishitems', wishitemSchema, 'wishitems');
 module.exports = mongoose.model('Cartitems', cartitemSchema, 'cartitems');
 module.exports = mongoose.model('Products',  productSchema,  'products');

/*Perhaps someone see something with the Products I'm not catching. I appreciate any 
 advice*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create 3 separate modules. You are overwriting the `module.exports` inside `Search.cjs` so you are only exporting the last one `Cartitems`. That means `Products`,  `Wishitems` and `Cartitems` are all models derived form the `cartitemSchema`.

Using your current schemas make these changes:

**Product.cjs**

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   _id:{
      type: String,
      required: true
   },
   name:{
      type: String,
      required: true
   }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Product',  productSchema,  'products');
```

**WishItem.cjs**

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const wishitemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   name:{
      type:String,
      required:true
   }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('WishItem', wishitemSchema, 'wishitems');
```

**CartItem.cjs**

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const cartitemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id:{
       type: String,
       required: true
    },
    name:{
       type: String,
       required: true
    }
}); 
module.exports = mongoose.model('CartItem', cartitemSchema, 'cartitems');
```

**app.js**

```js
//...
//...
const Product = require('../../../Product.cjs');
const WishItem = require('../../../WishItem.cjs');
const CartItem = require('../../../CartItem.cjs');
//...
//...
```

Here are some tips moving forward:

1. You don't need the third parameter in the `mongoose.model` function because with just `mongoose.model('Product',  productSchema);` mongoose will take the first argument `'Product'` and look for the lowercase pluralised collection name automatically. So `'Product' --> 'products'` and `'WishItem' --> 'wishitems'` etc.
2. If you can, leave the `_id` property alone, don't set it to `String`. Mongoose automatically adds one and sets it to an `ObjectId` which has so many benefits built in.

Answer (score 0):

Each `module.exports =`  line is *overwriting* the previous one.

Consider if you had an ordinary variable assigned like that:

```
 x = mongoose.model('Wishitems', wishitemSchema, 'wishitems');
 x = mongoose.model('Cartitems', cartitemSchema, 'cartitems');
 x = mongoose.model('Products',  productSchema,  'products');
```

You would expect `x` to have the last value assigned.

To return multiple things from a module, use an object, like:

```
 module.exports = {
    Wishitems: mongoose.model('Wishitems', wishitemSchema, 'wishitems');
    Cartitems: mongoose.model('Cartitems', cartitemSchema, 'cartitems');
    Products: mongoose.model('Products',  productSchema,  'products');
 }
```

Then when requiring that module, name the items:

```
{ Wishitems, Cartitems, Products } = require('../../../Search.cjs')
```